# zsh: command not found: dockerd

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-daemon

I have docker installed on my device
[image]

I am facing two issues

1. I was running `dockerd --dns` , I received

   zsh: command not found: dockerd
2. I am unable to call AWS RDS database from application inside docker container.

> docker run -p 1078:5001 -t test

[image]

Can someone please help?
I am new to CICD, Docker and Kubernetes.

Comment: hi, do you need to use `sudo` or install the package?

Comment: Is dockerd not install directly with docker installation?

Comment: I tried 
sudo dockerd 
resulting in asking for password and failing eventually

Comment: You might read through [ask] in the SO Help Center and revise this question.  You seem to be asking two totally separate questions (one non-programming question about installing Docker, and a separate question about RDS access in Kubernetes), and for each of them you need to include a [mcve] with enough detail to explain the problem.  Please do not include screenshots of terminal windows; paste the actual text of the code or error message into your question.

Comment: Note that in general, you shouldn't need to start `dockerd` yourself by hand -- it's a daemon, it should be started as a service by your init system / process supervisor. And because it's not _intended_ for users to start it by hand, it's quite reasonable for a packager to intentionally not put it somewhere in the PATH of regular/unprivileged users.